# What about expected performance in Pentaho?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I am using Pentaho to create ETL's and I am very focused on performance. I develop an ETL process that copy 163.000.000 rows from Sql server 2088 to PostgreSQL and it takes 17h.

I do not know how good or bad is this performance. Do you know how to measure if the time that takes some process is good? At least as a reference to know if I need to keep working heavily on performance or not.

Furthermore, I would like to know if it is normal that in the first 2 minutes of ETL process it load 2M rows. I calculate how long will take to load all the rows. The expected result is 6 hours, but then the performance decrease and it takes 17h.

I have been investigating in goole and I do not find any time references neither any explanations about performance.

Answer (score 3):

Divide and conquer, and proceed by elimination.

First, add a LIMIT to your query so it takes 10 minutes instead of 17 hours, this will make it a lot easier to try different things.

Are the processes running on different machines? If so, measure network bandwidth utilization to make sure it isn't a bottleneck. Transfer a huge file, make sure the bandwidth is really there.

Are the processes running on the same machine? Maybe one is starving the other for IO. Are source and destination the same hard drive? Different hard drives? SSDs? You need to explain...

Examine IO and CPU usage of both processes. Does one process max out one cpu core?

Does a process max out one of the disks? Check iowait, iops, IO bandwidth, etc.

How many columns? Two INTs, 500 FLOATs, or a huge BLOB with a 12 megabyte PDF in each row? Performance would vary between these cases...

Now, I will assume the problem is on the POSTGRES side.

Create a dummy table, identical to your target table, which has:

- Exact same columns (CREATE TABLE dummy LIKE table)
- No indexes, No constraints (I think it is the default, double check the created table)
- BEFORE INSERT trigger on it which returns NULL and drop the row.

The rows will be processed, just not inserted.

Is it fast now? OK, so the problem was insertion.

Do it again, but this time using an UNLOGGED TABLE (or a TEMPORARY TABLE). These do not have any crash-resistance because they don't use the journal, but for importing data it's OK.... if it crashes during the insert you're gonna wipe it out and restart anyway.

Still No indexes, No constraints. Is it fast?

If slow => IO write bandwidth issue, possibly caused by something else hitting the disks
If fast => IO is OK, problem not found yet!

With the table loaded with data, add indexes and constraints one by one, find out if you got, say, a CHECK that uses a slow SQL function, or a FK into a table which has no index, that kind of stuff. Just check how long it takes to create the constraint.

Note: on an import like this you would normally add indices and constraints after the import.

My gut feeling is that PG is checkpointing like crazy due to the large volume of data, due to too-low checkpointing settings in the config. Or some issue like that, probably random IO writes related. You put the WAL on a fast SSD, right?

Comment: I am also under the impression the main suspect is postgres journal. And the way you reach it is very systematic. Upvote.

Answer (score 2):

17H is too much. Far too much. For 200 Million rows, 6 hours is even a lot.

Hints for optimization:

1. Check the memory size: edit the spoon.bat, find the line containing -Xmx and change it to half your machine memory size. Details varies with java version. [Example for PDI V7.1](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0P0/100/090/040).
2. Check if the query from the source database is not too long (because too complex, or server memory size, or ?).
3. Check the target commit size (try 25000 for PostgresSQL), the `Use batch update for inserts` in on, and also that the index and constraints are disabled.
4. Play with the `Enable lazy conversion` in the `Table input`. Warning, you may produce difficult to identify and debug errors due to data casting.
5. In the transformation property you can tune the `Nr of rows in rowset` (click anywhere, select Property, then the tab Miscelaneous). On the same tab check the transformation is NOT `transactional`.

Comment: Thanks @AlainD

I have checked already all this points except the last one.
I have set memory to 6GB, and while the process is running pentaho never takes this 6 GB.
Query is a simple select *, takes a while, but I think that it is not the bottleneck.
Commitsize is set to 100.000 rows. I have been testing 10.000, 50.000 and 100.000 and even 500.000 and better performance is 100.000.
Can the last point be the key??

Comment: You are sure to have hack the spoon.bat (spoon.sh) to increase the JVM memory size? You have also

Comment: yes. I have seen that spoon.sh has been modified, and to ensure that I even add an environtment variable with the name of the memory variable in spoon.sh set to 6GB.

Comment: The issue may come from the Postsgres which puts the inserts in a journal for rollback or indexes or whatever reason. Check: remove this step and replace it with a dummy. Still 17 hours?

Comment: you mean remove the output table step? or which step?

Comment: Yes. Test if the issue comes from writing on Postgres. To check this, replace the suspect with a dumy and compare.

Comment: Finally I applied multithread in Pentaho output step. With a dummy step it took 15 minutes, but when I use multithread the data is loaded in 1hour and a half. Much better. Despite this, I believe that it is a lot of time. Maybe I try bulk loader for postgresql. Do u think it's a good idea?

Comment: Definitly. The issue is on the Postgres side. Remove all indexes and data-integrity checks, and journaling: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/wal.html]. Bulk load and make sure the transformation is not in `Transactional` mode (in parameters). After the transaction finishes, restablish the indexes and checks (which may take some time).

Comment: And, stupid question: is your jdbc driver up to date ? My colleague next door just had a performance issue because his ODBC/Access driver was outdated.